# How to convert a multi-line delimited string to a List<class>

Tags: c#, split, delimiter

I have a string delimited with new line.
I can split it to 4 different list items but I need also split the content of each string, where the items use the `|` character as separator.

The internal values use *Tags* like `BR=`, `KS=`.
I want to use the value of these *tags* to generate new class objects.
The class is named `BIRIM`; it has Property names corresponding to the *Tags* in the strings.

My String:

```
BR=PALET90|KS=90|IS=1
BR=PALET60|KS=60|IS=1
BR=EUROPALET|KS=55|IS=1
BR=EUROPALET66|KS=66|IS=1
BR=PALET|KS=75|IS=1
```

My Current Code:

```
 public class BIRIM {
  public string BR {get;set;}
  public int KS {get;set;}
  public int IS {get;set;}
}

 string birim = node2["BIRIMLER"]?.InnerText;

 string[] birimlerim = birim.Split(
      new[] { Environment.NewLine },
      StringSplitOptions.None
 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you can `Split` *several* times:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 string source = 
   @"BR=PALET90|KS=90|IS=1
     BR=PALET60|KS=60|IS=1
     BR=EUROPALET|KS=55|IS=1
     BR=EUROPALET66|KS=66|IS=1
     BR=PALET|KS=75|IS=1";

  ...

  var myList = source
    .Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(line => line
       .Split('|')
       .Select(item => item.Split('='))
       .ToDictionary(item => item[0].Trim(), item => item[1]))
    .Select(dict => new BIRIM() {
      BR = dict["BR"],
      KS = int.Parse(dict["KS"]),
      IS = int.Parse(dict["IS"])
    })
    .ToList();
```

However, I suggest implementing `TryParse` method within `BIRIM` class, let this class *parse for itself* when necessary:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

public class BIRIM {

  ...

  public static bool TryParse(string source, out BIRIM result) {
    result = null;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source))
      return false;

    string br = Regex.Match(source, @"BR\s*=\s*(\w+)").Groups[1].Value;
    string KS = Regex.Match(source, @"KS\s*=\s*([0-9]+)").Groups[1].Value;
    string IS = Regex.Match(source, @"IS\s*=\s*([0-9]+)").Groups[1].Value;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(br) && 
         int.TryParse(KS, out int aks) && 
         int.TryParse(IS, out int ais)) {
      result = new BIRIM() {
        BR = br,
        KS = aks,
        IS = ais,
      };

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

Then you can implement the loading as

```
  var myList = source
    .Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(line => BIRIM.TryParse(line, out var value) ? value : null)
    .Where(value => value != null)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: There's always a gothca in TryParse methods: what should be the correct behavior if TryParse fails? here you are just ignoring the "wrong" lines. This means actually swallowing a problem (the source string is somehow wrong?) and ignoring it. According to the case, this may be not the best choice.
In general, I prefer handle as an error what is a "logical" error, instead of going on as nothing happened: it usually leads to further errors / misbehavior in the program, likely harder to understand and fix

Comment: Gian Paolo: I thought my to demonstrate *single responsibility* principle with `TryParse`: class should *parse for itself*. As for the implementation we can ignore parse errors or throw exception, or even collect errors and then throw exception with list of problem. Same for `TryParse`: my code tolerares chunks swapping (first KS then BR) which is not necessary the best policy

Comment: nothing wrong in a TryParse method in itself and the way you implemented in in your sample, also satisfying the SRP. It's the usage of it that is "dangerous" when someone just ignore a false return value. Sometimes it can be the right choice, most of the time I think (and possibly in this case as well), the program should somehow handle the problem "the input was somehow wrong, I should do something instead of just ignore the wrong input". Of course, decide how to handle a wrong input is a responsibility of the caller, not the BRIM class itself.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of Environment.NewLine :

```
 string[] birimlerim = birim.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to split multiple times

One implementation could be the following, but please consider to split it in more functions, it will be more readable and you can parse converted value.

```
    private static List<BIRIM> ParseBirim(string birimText)
    {
        var birims = new List<BIRIM>();

        string[] birimlerim = birimText.Trim().Split(Environment.NewLine);

        foreach (string birim in birimlerim)
        {
            string[] bki = birim.Split('|');

            birims.Add(new BIRIM
            {
                BR = bki[0].Split('=')[1],
                KS = Convert.ToInt32(bki[1].Split('=')[1]),
                IS = Convert.ToInt32(bki[2].Split('=')[1]),
            });
        }

        return birims;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option.
Parse the whole multi-line content using [Regex.Matches()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches) (specifying `RegexOptions.Multiline`), iterate the [MatchCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection) items to build new `BIRIM` objects with the values extracted.

```
string pattern = @"^BR=(?<br>.*?)\|KS=(?<ks>.*?)\|IS=(?<is>.*?)$";
string innerText = node2["BIRIMLER"]?.InnerText;

var birims = Regex.Matches(innerText, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
    .OfType<Match>().Select(m => 
        new BIRIM(
            m.Groups["br"].Value,
            int.Parse('0' + m.Groups["ks"].Value.Trim()),
            int.Parse('0' + m.Groups["is"].Value.Trim())))
    .ToList();
```

This handles null `KS` and `IS` values, converting to empty/null values to `0`.
Adapt as needed.

---

I've added a Constructor to your `BIRIM` class that accepts arguments that match the Type of its Properties.
If you cannot modify the class structure, use the syntax (`new T() { PropertyName = PropertyValue }`):

```
public class BIRIM
{
    public BIRIM(string sbr, int sks, int sis) {
        BR = sbr; KS = sks; IS = sis;
    }

    public string BR { get; set; }
    public int KS { get; set; }
    public int IS { get; set; }
}
```